# MISP to Microsoft Graph Security Script - Not working

Tags: python, security, microsoft-graph-api, advanced-threat-protection

Followed https://github.com/microsoftgraph/security-api-solutions/tree/master/Samples/MISP documentation, added MISP URL plus Token, Microsoft Graph API application tenant, APP ID and Token etc, but is not working when running the script.

Just added the value "test.com" and got the following message:

`/home/*username*/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1045: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host '*MISPurl.com*'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings`

But nothing else, no error nor troubleshooting possible as far as I can see.
Checked the following:

- There is no additional error message after running the script
- There is no logs folder to check for errors

Would you have any idea?
Regards!

- Checked MISP URL
- Checked MISP TOKEN
- Checked Azure APP Permissions are right
- Checked connectivity between my console and the MISP instance

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to failure of validation certificated , as per the [doc](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/security-api-solutions/tree/master/Samples/MISP) It is recommended to use a valid SSL cert in production and change this value to True.

[image]

Hope this will fix the issue

Thanks